# How can I duplicate the "Birthday" calendar from 2020 to 2021?

Tags: google-calendar

I have a  Google calendar "Birthday" and want to duplicate the events from 2020 to 2021 without manually typing them all again.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications SE](/Tour). Please add additional  details to help us understand the problem. See [ask].

Comment: Is this a custom calendar you created and named  "Birthday" or is this an automatically generated calendar from Google Contacts? Are you familiar with event recurrence? How many events are we talking about?  Is it reasonable to just duplicate the events but change the dates or edit each event to set it up as a recurring event? Both of those avoid starting from scratch but could be time consuming if you have a large number of events. Please [edit] your question to include additional details to help us understand your needs.

Answer (score 0):

To get events to repeat every year on a specific day of the month:

1. Edit the event (Click the event, click the pen icon)
2. Under the date range you will see a dropdown with "Does not repeat". Click it.
3. Select "Annually on..."
4. Click Save

This is also available when you add a new event.